# CSS Animation: Fade Out permanently

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a div, which I fade-in (right to left) with css:

```
CSS:
#mydiv {
   animation: slideIn 1s ease 0s 1;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

When I click on a close-button, it should fade-out the same way:

```
JS:
$("#close").on('click', function(e) {
  $("#mydiv").css({ 'animation': 'slideOut 1s ease 0s 1' });
});

CSS:
@keyframes slideOut {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

The fade-out animation works, but after the fade-out, mydiv immediately appears back at the initial position. What can I do to prevent this? Using jQuery to set `display:none` after the animation, suppresses the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to your element, and the animation will remain at the end.

Comment: Thanks, `$("#mydiv").css({ 'animation': 'slideOut 1s ease 0s 1 forwards' });` does the job.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe what you are looking for is `animation-fill-mode` Property.
It makes the `<div>` element retain the style values from the last keyframe when the animation ends. You can read about this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp)